# How to return an element in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

In my code i have an array that is like below:

```
localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks = [object , object, object]
```

Now i want to iterate over the array using a forEach loop and return when the id of an object matches the id i provide , let me lay out the code to make my example clear.

```
storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.forEach(function(e, i){
    if (e.task_Id === task_Id) {
        return e;
    }
});
```

But wheni run the code even if the if conditon passes and e is returned , `storeRelevantObj` still remains empty , why ? why is the return statement not working ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `forEach()` for filtering, use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead:

```
var storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.filter(function(e) {
     return e.task_Id === task_Id;
})[0];
```

If you don't mind IE support, you can use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method that is returning the first element that satisfies the condition (it's also more performant since it can return immediately upon first match):

```
var storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.find(function(e) {
     return e.task_Id === task_Id;
});
```

Also, if you're targeting ES6 or using a transpiler (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)), your predicate can be expressed using an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.find(e => e.task_Id === task_Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `Array#forEach`

With `Array#forEach`, empty array could be initialized and do `Array#push` if condition is met!

Using `Array#filter`, *new array with all elements that pass the test* is returned!

```js
var storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.filter(function(e, i) {
  return e.task_Id === task_Id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a filter function here. Because you want to return an array. The forEach you are currently using will keep overwriting the value of storeRelevantObj.

Code:

`storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.filter((e, i)=>{
    return (e.task_Id === task_Id);
});`

If you need to use forEach, you should do this:

`localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.forEach((e, i)=>{
    if (e.task_Id === task_Id){
         storeRelevantObj.push(e)

    };
});`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array#filter`, will return a new array . you can use also use `Array#reduce`.

 `var storeRelevantObj = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  return prev || cur.task_id == task_id;
}, false);`

However this will only return the first matched value. While `filter` will return an array with all matched values

Answer (score 0):

The following [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) states that there is no way out of a forEach other than throwing an exception. It also mentions what your options are if you need such behavior!

You can also use a simple for loop the following way:

```
localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks = [object , object, object];

var i, l, match;


l =  localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks.length;
for(i=0;!match&&i<l;++i){
    match = localStroge_Procrastinator_tasks[i].task_Id === task_Id;
}
```

if match is set to true inside the loop then next evaluation will not proceed!